# Ember-cli models written in CoffeeScript

Tags: coffeescript, ember-cli

Using ember-cli with ember-cli-coffeescript installed. If I define a model named Person in pure javascript (see below) it works just fine.

file: models/person.js

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  nome: DS.attr('string')
});
```

But when I try to use coffeScript I get an error message stating that the Person model is not defined. See the coffeScript bellow, what am I missing here?

```
`import DS from 'ember-data';`

Person = DS.Model.extend
  nome: DS.attr('string')

`export default Person;`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some requirements to be met for your code to run fine:

- [ember-cli-coffeescript](https://github.com/kimroen/ember-cli-coffeescript) installed
- file extension is `.coffee`
- full path: `app/models/person.coffee`
- no `app/models/person.js` present at the same time (when `person.coffee` is present)

Everything should be working without using `;` after `import` and after `export`:

```
`import DS from 'ember-data'`

Person = DS.Model.extend
  nome: DS.attr 'string'

`export default Person`
```